# PHP - Verificar pagina que esta rodando

Tags: php

Tenho um arquivo config.php, todos os outros arquivos do site o inclui.

Estou com dificuldades em como verificar qual a pagina que o config.php esta rodando atualmente.

Único exemplo que achei foi usando o is_page porem sem sucesso

```
if(is_page('about')){
    echo "estou na pagina about";
}else{
    echo "não estou na pagina about";
}
```

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: **WordPress** ?

Comment: Pois é, essa função `is_page` tem cara de ser do WordPress. Sem ele, você pode utilizar a `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, que possui a URI acessada.

Comment: Funcionou certinho amigo

Comment: Você pode colocar em todas as páginas, antes do include config.php  uma variável com o nome da página, exemplo: na página about  `$pagina="about";` na página home `$pagina="Home";` etc... Na `config.php`  coloca ` echo "estou na pagina ". $pagina;`